# Ajax in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I have been following this article about how to use Ajax in Rails:

http://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails

And so far as I understand, Rails does most of the code it self right?
All that is done there it self is in thoes partials like this:

```
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if @product.errors.any? %>
  <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  $(".product-index").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'index') %>")
  $("#product-modal").modal("hide")
<% end %>
```

And thoes  just seem to take care of when the partial form should show up and when it should go away.

Is that right? That I don't need to learn much of Ajax it self, and this is just fine which is shown there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That js files execute only after your call to certain actions of the controller.

You have a controller with actions like create/delete... So when you create a record, using **create** action, Rails executes **create.js** Same thing happens with other actions.

But in some situations, for e.g if you want a button to send some specific data with ajax you'll have to make something other than that in that tutorial.

But you're right, you don't have to know much ajax at the beginning.

Comment: But when it loads the create.js,  the file it self renders the form. And the form only makes the modal go away right? So no real code needed in the create.js? Edit:  I mean it loads the save file not form

Comment: In your example create.js just renders save partial. All stuff are made there. So, you're right - no real codin in create.js

Answer (score 1):

for using jquery in rails and unobtrusive javascript I recommend watching these two casts from railscasts ,very helpful

http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: Very nice videos! Learned a lot.